# How can I sum up same index for several different lists vertically in python 3?

Tags: python-3.x, csv

So I have a CSV file that outputs several lists of numbers that aren't assigned to a variable and I'm wondering how I can possibly sum up the same index for each list vertically to output a single list that has the sum of each index of every list vertically.

Current Code:

```
import CSV

with open('Superheroes.csv', 'r') as csvfile:
    first_line = csvfile.readline()
    super_reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')

for vote in super_reader:
    vote.pop(0)
    vote1 = [(x if x else '0') for x in vote]
    vote2 = list(map(int, vote1))
    print(vote2)
    
csvfile.close()
```

[Example of lists contained in CSV file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2NpFW.png)

Example:
So for the three lists shown in the picture, I want the output to be [18, 18, 13, 13, 11, 13, 15, 18, 13, 15, 16, 8]

Any advice?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use `zip`

**Ex:**

```
with open('Superheroes.csv', 'r') as csvfile:
    first_line = csvfile.readline()
    super_reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
    result = []
    for vote in super_reader:
        vote.pop(0)
        result.append([int(x) if x else 0 for x in vote])
        
result = [sum(i) for i in zip(*result)]
print(result)
```